# How are wires placed inside extending single-wire headphones?

Tags: wiring

I'd like to know how wires are placed inside the part that connects left and right ear pieces together that allows them to extend significantly without any problems.

Here's the type of the headphones I'm talking about:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the appropriate tags, so please edit them as you see fit.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question without a picture.  Please post a picture of the type of headphone you're asking about.

Comment: Are you asking why asymmetrical headphones don't problems mechanically, electrically or both? If you are asking about the electrical aspect, what is it you want to know? How the impedance is matched or how they fit the wires in a single cable?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: The question is asking how wires can be routed through a telescoping type of housing as is present on the headphone band.  A simple solution would be a coiled wire, thick enough that it can't become pinched in the telescoping mechanism.  Sliding contacts would likely cause painful noise inconsistent-contact noise any time the band were subject to forces while wearing.

Comment: There are many videos and images of disassembly of various models. Try to find one for the particular model you are interested in. I saw at least two for the Sennheiser HD 580 that you posted in the picture.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is off-topic because of not being about electronic design. I thought wires are pretty commonly used in electronics.

Comment: This question is not asking about the electrical characteristics of the wires (electronic engineering) it is asking about the mechanical design and mechanical properties of the wires (mechanical engineering).

Comment: Is there a SE site for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this has been downvoted a bit, I still think it is a good question because there is a lot of ingenuity in these designs. I have disassembled a fair few of these types of headphones and I can say that there is no single solution.

By far the most often used way is just a bent flat flex - very wide, and very thin. My Logitech H800 uses this technique. Apparently, it is acceptable to have about 2mm-radius bends in this material, probably provided you use very thin copper to avoid cracking.

Another option that I have seen used in my Sennheiser is to have a long serpentine flat flex going all around from one ear to the other. This seems to me like total overkill, and because of the limited available copper I suspect this is only possible with very low current signals (like just driving a headphone coil). This would not be possible in the Logitech example, because that device also carries battery/charging power over the flat flex.

Lastly, in a very cheap headset I have seen just sliding contacts being used. I suspect this to be very low endurance, as exemplified by the short lifetime of that headset.

Comment: I have a recollection of a set of phones from before the 1970's that used the two spring arches for the structural strength and the electrical connection to the other drive unit.  I think it had a separate exposed wire loop to jump over the adjustable part to maintain rigidity.